# Do the improper integrals converge?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I want to check if the following improper integrals converge or not.

- $\displaystyle{\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}\, dt}$

I have done the following:
$$\ln t\leq t \Rightarrow \frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}\leq \frac{t}{1+t^2} \Rightarrow \int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}\, dt\leq \int_1^{+\infty}\frac{t}{1+t^2}\, dt\Rightarrow \int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}\, dt\leq \left [\ln |1+t^2|^2 \right ]_1^{+\infty}$$
The right side does not converge, so we cannot use this inequality to apply the comparison test.

Could you give me a hint which inquality we have to use?

- $\displaystyle{\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin t}{t}\, dt}$ :

We have that $\displaystyle{\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin t}{t}\, dt=\lim_{b\rightarrow +\infty}\int_0^{b}\frac{\sin t}{t}\, dt}$
$$\int_0^{b}\frac{\sin t}{t}\, dt=\int_0^{b}\sin (t)\cdot \frac{1}{t}\, dt=\int_0^{b}\left (-\cos t\right )'\cdot \frac{1}{t}\, dt=\left [\left (-\cos t\right )\cdot \frac{1}{t}\right ]_0^b+\int_0^{b}\cos t\cdot \left (\frac{1}{t}\right )'\, dt=\left [-\cos t \cdot \frac{1}{t}\right ]_0^b+\int_0^{b}\cos t\cdot \left (-\frac{1}{t^2}\right )\, dt=\left [-\cos t \cdot \frac{1}{t}\right ]_0^b-\int_0^{b}\cos t\cdot \frac{1}{t^2} \, dt$$
Is this correct so far?

- $\displaystyle{\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos t}{t^2}\, dt}$ :

I have done the following:
$$\left |\frac{1-\cos t}{t^2}\right |=\frac{|1-\cos t|}{t^2}\leq \frac{1+|\cos t|}{t^2}\leq \frac{1+1}{t^2}=\frac{2}{t^2}$$
It holds that $$\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{2}{t^2}\, dt=\left [\frac{2}{t^2}\right ]_1^{+\infty}=2$$ From the comparison test it follows that $\displaystyle{\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos t}{t^2}\, dt}$ converges.

Comment: For the first integral, you could use the fact that $\frac{1}{1+t^{2}} \leq \frac{1}{t^{2}}$ and $ln(t) \leq t^{p}$ for all $p>0, t$ sufficiently large

Comment: So you mean to have $$\frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}\leq \frac{t}{t^2}\Rightarrow \int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}\, dt\leq \int_1^{+\infty}\frac{t}{t^2}\, dt\Rightarrow \int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}\, dt\leq \int_1^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t}\, dt$$ But again the right integral goes to infinity, or not? @TomAriel

Comment: No, i meant using something like $p=0.5$ for example. But yes, the right integral goes to infinity

Comment: Ah ok, so we get $$\frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}\leq \frac{t^{\frac{1}{2}}}{t^2}\Rightarrow \int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}\, dt\leq \int_1^{+\infty}t^{-\frac{3}{2}}\, dt \\ \Rightarrow \int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}\, dt\leq \left [\frac{t^{-\frac{3}{2}+1}}{-\frac{3}{2}+1}\right ]_1^{+\infty}=\left [\frac{t^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{-\frac{1}{2}}\right ]_1^{+\infty}=2$$ and since this is finite, i.e the right integral is convergent so is also the left one, right? @TomAriel

Comment: Yes, exactly right

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you!! What about the other two limits? @TomAriel

Answer (score 1):

For the first one,,,we can use the comparison test (limit form)

Take $g= \frac{1}{x^{3/2}} $ ,

Now , $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{x^{3/2} \cdot \ln(x) }{1+ x^2} = 0 $

Now , as $\int_{1}^{+\infty}  \frac{1}{x^{3/2}} $ Converge, so, $\int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2} $ is also convergent..

For the second one,,, write , $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{sin(x)}{x} + \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{sin(x)}{x} $
As,$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{sin(x)}{x} $ is clearly convergent,,we go for $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{sin(x)}{x} $,

take $f=sin(x) , g= \frac{1}{x} $

Clearly, $g$ is monotone decreasing and bounded on $[1,\infty)$, and $\lim_{x\to \infty} g = 0 $

And also $|\int_{1}^{K} sin(x)| = | -cos(K) + cos(1) | \le 2 $

Now , by Dirichlet's test, $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{sin(x)}{x} $ is convergent.

For the third one,,your done is okk.

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you!! What about the other two limits?

Comment: Why do we split the second one into an integral on $(0,1)$ and an integral on $(1, +\infty)$ ?

Comment: Just for easily taking, $g$ as decreasing one.

Comment: Why is $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{sin(x)}{x}$ convergent? I got stuck right now

Comment: Since, it's a proper integral.

Comment: And proper integral always converge,,,you can test,,that there is no point in $[0,1]$ , where this integral has infinite discontinuity.

Answer (score 1):

For the second integral you can just use $\int_{1}^{t} \frac{sin(t')}{t'} = -[\frac{cos(t')}{t'}]_{1}^{t} - \int_{1}^{t} \frac{cos(t')}{t'^{2}}$

Comment: But the original integral is from 0 not from 1

Comment: Yes, but the integral over $[0,1]$ is proper considering the function $sinc(x)$ is continuous, so we can just ignore that part

Comment: I haven't really understood why we can ignore the part $[0,1]$. Could you explain that further to me?

Comment: @Mary Star ok, for your convenience, as we know, $sin(x) \le x $ on $[0,1]$, Now $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{sin(x)}{x} \le \int_{0}^{1} (1) $